# Angular js ng show not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a small web app and facing an issue.

I want to show a preloader svg inside a div as below :-

```
<div class="loader" ng-show="main.showLoader">
<svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
</svg>
```

In my HTML I switched **main.showLoader = true** on click of a button.

Controller Function :-

```
$scope.setCA=function(cont,click){

    if($scope.aC!=null){

        $scope.aC={};                           
    }
        if($scope.c[c.p]==null){ 
            $scope.mC='';

            .....Server interactions here 


                var chat={
                    'name':cont.name,
                    'phone':cont.phone,
                    'msgs':msgs,
                    'unreadMsgs':unreads,
                };

                $scope.chats[cont.phone]=chat;                  //Assign the messages from repective users in the chats array to the respective contact phone number as here                        
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.activeChats[cont.phone]=chat;
                    if(click)
                        $scope.setChatInFocus($scope.chats[cont.phone]);        //Send chats to setChatinFocus       
                });
            });
        }
        else{
            $scope.showFirstTime = false;
            if($scope.activeChats[cont.phone]==null){
                $scope.activeChats[cont.phone]=$scope.chats[cont.phone];
            }
            if(click)
                $scope.setChatInFocus($scope.chats[cont.phone]);    
        }
        setTimeout(function(){scrollToBottom()},10);
         this.showLoader=false;
    };
```

HTML:-

```
<div class="singleContact person" ng-cloak ng-class="{active: contactName === contact.name}" 
 ng-repeat="contact in contacts"
 ng-click='main.showLoader=true;setChatActive({ "name": contact.name, "phone": contact.phone },true)>
```

It switches on as intended but does not go off.
Some help ?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it's hard to know for sure, but it would appear either the context of `this` inside the callback function is not `main` or you need to run `$scope.$apply();` at the end of the function.

Comment: you need to show that function triggered by the button

Comment: have you used ng-click?

Comment: <div class="singleContact person" ng-cloak ng-class="{active: contactName === contact.name}" 
  ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-click='main.showLoader=true;setCA({ "name": contact.name, "phone": contact.phone },true)>

Comment: its a bit hard to get the full context, my guess would be a multiple scope problem...
can you please post the html including the button to help understand better the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `var self = this;` at the top of your controller and change it to `self.showLoader = false`

In the current context, `this` is the function you are in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the properties are placed on different objects. When you enable the *loader*, the code sets `$scope.main.showLoader` to `true`. The timeout callback on the other hand sets a variable `this.showLoader` to `false`. As @tpie already explained, `this` in this case only references to the timeout callback function itself.

The HTML snippet you posted is not complete, so I can only guess. Using the following line to reset `showLoader` can solve the problem.

```
$scope.main.showLoader=false;
```